# Comparing a subset of a dataframe to the full one with percentages

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hypothetically, if I had a dataframe containing ages of children who participated in a spelling bee with a column containing the last round the child made it to. How could I find the percentage of children that made it to the last round?

I get that I have to take a subset, but I'm not sure which function to use for comparing the amount of values in the subset versus the main df in order to get a percentage as an answer. What tools could i use?

Answer (score 0):

You could simply try:

```py
df[df["round"] == last_round].shape[0] / df.shape[0]

# where last_round is of type int
# df.shape[0] returns the number of rows
```